# Reducer "loading" returned undefined during initialization - combineReducers

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I'm trying to create a destination if there is none with that name in the list. The creation fails with error:

> Reducer "loading" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you ...

I tracked the issue down to `combineReducers`, more speficially the reducers `loading` and `errors`. Both give same error, if the other one is commented out. If both are commented out, then the program seems to work, but I assume they are here for a bigger reason and removing them isn't an option.

Havent found a solution or a bigger clue from other similar posts (how would you even fit an `initialState` next to `TState`?). Also, this is the first time I work with Typescript and Redux in my short coder career, so the solution may be obvious for somebody, but I've struggled with it the whole day today. So, please help...

**DestinationCreateView.js**

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    destinationReducer,
    loading,
    errors,
});
```

**errorReducer.ts** (loadingReducer.ts is almost identical)

```
import type { PayloadAction, SerializedError } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export default <TState>(state: TState & { errors: Record<string, unknown> }, action: PayloadAction) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;
    const matches = /\[(.*)]\s(TRIGGER|REQUEST|FAILURE)([_\w]+)*/.exec(type);

    if (!matches) return state;

    const [, stateKey, requestState, extra] = matches;
    const storageKey = extra ? `${stateKey}-${extra.substr(1).toLowerCase()}` : stateKey;
    return {
        ...state,
        errors: {
            ...state.errors,
            [storageKey]: requestState === 'FAILURE' ? payload : null,
        },
    };
};
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing combineReducers with reduceReducers did the thing:

```
const reducer = reduceReducers(
    {
        ...initialState,
        loading: { [DESTINATION_DUCK_PREFIX]: true },
        errors: {},
    },
    destinationReducer,
    loading,
    errors,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning a default value to your `state` and yet your `reducer` has a branch directly returning `state`. For store initialization, your reducer is called with an `undefined` state on the first action, so you **need** to return some default value.

That's why most hand-written reducers have the signature

```
const myReducer = (state: StateType = initialState, action: ActionType): StateType => {}
```

You are missing the `= initialState`.

All that said, you probably should not be writing "full" Reducers by hand nowadays, generally we recommend writing all your Redux logic with the official Redux Toolkit. Take a look at the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) to learn that :)

Comment: I'm aware about the missing `initialState` (I mentioned it above). Question is, how to fit the `initialState` into there, without rewriting the logic completely? I've tried many ways, but there's always some part that doesn't like it.

Comment: Rereading again, the question is more: how would you ever define `<TSTATE>` when using this? It will always fall back to `unknown` with `combineReducers`.
This might be a xy-problem. What problem are you actually trying to solve? I assume this might be quite easily solvable with `createSlice`, `extraReducers` and `addMatcher`

Comment: Honest answer would be: I don't know. [This](https://medium.com/stashaway-engineering/react-redux-tips-better-way-to-handle-loading-flags-in-your-reducers-afda42a804c6)  was the source of this logic, but the `<TState>` was added due to unknown reason to me. My current goal is to get rid of this error without changing too much, as it may brake something somewhere else. TY, I will look into the `createSlice`, `extraReducers` and `addMatcher`.

Comment: If you use `createAsyncThunk`, you can just `builder.addMatcher(isPending, (state, action) => ...)`. (see https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters ) 
But if this is only about loading state, you might also just want to have RTK manage that completely and use RTK-Query.